# Dart: How to make a class trigger?

Tags: html, dart

html

```
<button class="btn btn-control" (click)="toggle($event)" *ngFor="let el of menuL">{{el}}</button>
```

dart

```
void toggle(MouseEvent e) {
 print(e.target.classes );
}
```

> [error] The getter 'classes' isn't defined for the class 'EventTarget'. (package:angular_tour_of_heroes/src/components/dashboard/dashboard.dart, line 45, col 20)

dart

```
void toggle(MouseEvent e) {
 e.target.classes.toggle('active');
}
```

> [error] The getter 'classes' isn't defined for the class 'EventTarget'. (package:angular_tour_of_heroes/src/components/dashboard/dashboard.dart, line 44, col 14)

How to do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HtmlElement elem = e.target;
elem.classes.toggle('active');
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.